# What are the allowed "Default Value Literal" for an EList-typed EAttribute in an EMF Ecore model?

Tags: java, eclipse, ecore

I want to build an .ecore model. I am using Eclipse Neon. in Design mode, I have a `class` and inside the class I have few `attributes`. when I set type of the attribute to `EEList<E> [org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList]`, I can't set the **Default Value Literal**. I don't know what is the valid value.
[image]

Comment: [1] I don't know anything about Ecore, but is [Bug 298910 - empty Default Value Literal of an EAttribute generates error](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298910) relevant? [2] What is displayed if you click help (the question mark icon) for the _Default Value Literal_ field?

Comment: about the "question mark", it is not really useful. it's a pop-up that "Default Value Literal, must be a valid literal of the attribute's type."!!!! About the Bug, YES, seems it is a bug. I had another warning too, that is described on the Bug Report Page. I was waiting to solve current problem first, but seems these are connected to each other!  Thank you for your help and I am wondering how you find this bug report page... it can be a clue for my next searches.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it seems you cannot set a default literal value for ELists. Or at least I could find no reference to it in any documentation, nor in the code.

For what purpose are you defining an EAttribute of type EList ? If you simply want a multi-valued feature (e.g. List) you should instead have an EAttribute of type X with multiplicity [0..*].